# jQuery dropdown navigation

Tags: jquery

I am using simple jQuery code to make drop down navigation, but its not giving expected results...

**jquery code**

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav li').hover(function () {
            $('ul', this).slideDown(100);
        }, function () {
            $('ul', this).slideUp(100);     
        });
});
```

**html code**

```
<ul class="nav radius clearfix">
    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
        <ul class="radius">
            <li><a href="#">Recent Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Archive Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">New Project</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please check and let me know what's I am missing. thanks.

Comment: What's "not expected"? It seems fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/APzxv/

Comment: What result do you expect? I tried, and seems good ([see here your example](http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/G5Pjv/))

Comment: @expertCode try mouseover on projects and it shows hides continuously. i am using firefox.

Comment: @seoppc i tried at firefox, and works normally

Comment: Tested in FF 6.0.2 and works fine.

Comment: @expertCode, i think my css is making issues, should i paste css as well?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: to address the animation "flickering issue" in addition to starting in a closed state, you can use the following (check it on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/32xEj/1/)). It's not very elegant but this issue arises from the way some browsers handle the change in size of the elements involved, and this does resolve that:

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav li').hover(function () {

        $('ul:not(:animated)', this).slideDown(100);
        }, function () {
            $('ul:not(:animated)', this).slideUp(100);     
        });
    $('.nav li ul').slideUp(0);
});
```

Comment: its showing problem here, when i mouseover on projects, it slidesdown fine, but when i try to select(hover) any child element for example recent projects,  it does something weird animation.

Comment: but its still giving some problems, should i paste my css as well? or can you write this code in another way.

Comment: What problems are you getting?

Comment: I've updated it  & the fiddle to use a different technique to "stop()".

Answer (score 0):

Try this -- it adds a delay to keep the "flickering" you're sometimes experiencing.

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav li').hover(function () {
            $('ul', this).delay(50).stop().slideDown(100);
        }, function () {
            $('ul', this).delay(50).stop().slideUp(100);     
        });
});
```

Comment: its still giving issues, should i paste my css as well?

Comment: Your flicker problem is inconsistent, at least for me. I only experienced it once so far.